# RSS Feed from Site to Facebook Fanpage

Tags: facebook, wordpress, rss

I have a WordPress based site and a Facebook fanpage. I want to include my site RSS feed to the page, in the FBML tab. I tried some JSs, but those didn't work. How can I do this? I want my RSS shows up in a Static FBML tab, not in the note.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty straightforward to do--what you'll need to do is create a new app for the fanpage and set it to be a Page Tab. From there, you can have it just load a page on your server as an iframe.

Granted, you'll need to set up something like MagpieRSS in order to be read off that page, but it's pretty simple if you're not looking to push wall posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this in PHP:

```
     $doc = new DOMDocument();
      $doc->load('https://www.mywebsite.com/rss.php');

      foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
               /*
do things with the item
           */               
        }
```